# How can I get some padding between these form boxes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display 2 form boxes on one line and another below them.  Anything I try with divs cannot get these 2 fields to separate.  I've even tried to insert `&nbsp;` between them with no luck.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="form-line">
  <input class="input-text" id="name-box" type="text" name="name" value="Name">
  <input class="input-text" id="mail-box" type="text" name="mail" value="Email">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-text {
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input {
  display: inline;
}

.form-line {
  padding-top: 5px;
  clear:both;
}

#name-box {
  float: left;
}

#mail-box {
  float: left;
}
```

Can you please give me an idea of how to put 10px between these boxes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `input`s as `display:inline-block` (will not work on IE 8 and below except if you hack it a little):

```
input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;


    /** Just for IE <= 8 */
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5QvH/).

Comment: Did you mean below instead of above?

Comment: Indeed, it's fixed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To arrange the second to the right of the first:

```
.form-line>input{display:inline-block}
.form-line>input+input{margin-left:10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give margin-left to the mail box , so your mail box css will be

```
#mail-box {
  float: left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```